# Mean_intensity attribute of regionprops returns different values depending on the block_size specified in the threshold_local method

Tags: python, scikit-image, threshold

I assume this is just a beginner's mistake as I have been working with python 3.6.x for about three months and scikit-image for less than that amount of time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem is that the mean_intensity attribute of regionprops returns different values depending on the block_size specified in the threshold_local method, here set to 33.

My understanding of regionprops is that mean_intensity would be calculated on the basis of the original input image. If that's the case, then why would mean_intensity values vary as the threshold calculated by threshold_local changes.

Input is the following uint16 grayscale .tif image: [slice 1.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/41nlkuoohfvn1f2/slice%201.tif?dl=0). Here's the code I'm working with:

```
from skimage import io

from skimage import morphology
from skimage.filters import threshold_local
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

from numpy import flip
from pandas import DataFrame

def start():
    while True:
        us_input = input(
            "Please enter the name of the file you'd like to analyze.\n> "
        )

        try:
            im = io.imread(us_input)
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("That file doesn't seem to exist or has been entered incorrectly.")

    detect(im)

def detect(image):
    local_thresh = threshold_local(image, 33, offset=30)
    binary_im = image > local_thresh

    label_im = label(binary_im) 
    interest_im = morphology.remove_small_objects(label_im, min_size=14.7) # ignore objects below 5um
    label_interest_im = label(interest_im)

    props(label_interest_im, image)


def props(label_interest_im, image):
    results = []
    im_props = regionprops(label_interest_im, intensity_image=image, cache=False)

    for blob in im_props:
        properties = []
        yx_coords = blob.centroid
        xy_coords = flip(yx_coords, 0)
        real_xy_coords = (xy_coords / .769230769230769) # pixel to um conversion
        round_xy_coords = real_xy_coords.round(1)
        properties.append(round_xy_coords[0])
        properties.append(round_xy_coords[1])
        properties.append(blob.mean_intensity.round(2))

        results.append(properties)

    results = DataFrame(results, columns = ['x_coord', 'y_coord', 'mean_intensity'])
    results.index = results.index + 1

    print(results)

start()
```

Comment: Your code example is incomplete; here you've just provided two functions.  Please also show us how you load your data and apply the functions to it.  Giving us a link to an example .tif also wouldn't hurt, then we can run your code and see where it misbehaves.

Comment: Hello Stefan! I literally just finished watching your Scipy 2018 presentation. Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated. I assume I'm just not understanding the underlying thresholding technique. --Sean

Comment: Glad you found the tutorial! I don't see the numbers varying depending on the window size here (I get 1, 332.2, 332.2, 4.52). Note that `remove_small_objects` should operate on the binary image, not the labels (the code you gave above raises a warning, indicating this).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the code! After reading the documentation, it was my understanding that remove_small_objects operates on already-labeled objects. In any case, oddly enough, no warnings are raised when I run the code. As for the numbers you got, I think my image file was converted to .png when I uploaded to stackoverflow as the results I get are much different. I've edited my question to include a dropbox link to the original image.

Comment: You're right: it accepts both labeled and unlabeled images, so no problem there. The reason the outputs change is because you are calculating regions based on label_interest_im`, which depends on the output of thresholding.  So even if your original image is used to calculate the values, if your regions change, you'll get different results.

Comment: So are you saying that the only correct usage of regionprops is to label the original image and employ that labeled image as well as the original ("unthresholded") image as arguments in regionprops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean intensity works by finding the mean intensity in the original image *based on the regions in the label image*. These regions will change depending on your thresholding. To get a clear understanding, I suggest, for each `threshold_local` window size, have a look at the resulting labeled objects. (You can use `skimage.color.label2rgb`.) You will see that these are different, so it is not surprising that they give different mean intensity values.

Comment: Hello Juan! Thanks for your response. I think I know what you're saying but I also suspect that I haven't formulated my question precisely. Running my code on the image linked above returns a mean intensity of 34351.71 for labeled object 21 at x,y-coordinates 301.8, 383.4. However, if I change the block size from 33 to, say, 25, I return a mean intensity value of 41337.03. If, as you say, mean_intensity from `regionprops` finds the mean intensity in the original image, why should this vary if the block size in `threshold_local` changes? Shouldn't only intensities for thresholded image change?

Comment: So just to be clear, my question concerns the intensity value for a particular labeled object in the image and how this varies according to the block size argument in `threshold_local`. Forgive me if I'm being obtuse. As I indicate above, I'm quite new to python and scikit-image.

Comment: @Gextra11 What I'm saying is that object 21 will be not be the same object for different block sizes. It might be the same object but with pixels added or removed, or it might be a different object altogether, because even the number of objects could change. To check on your objects, use `plt.imshow(color.label2rgb(thresh))` for different thresholded images.

Comment: Ok, and depending on the pixels found to belong to an object, the intensity will vary. So with a particular block size, only x pixels, whatever their intensity, will be considered when calculating mean intensity of an object in the original image. Sorry for being so slow on the uptake.

Comment: Hi Juan! Thanks for your help. I just figured out that you‘re the Juan from the Scipy 2018 tutorial. I really appreciate and like the fact that you took time for my beginner‘s questions. Cheers! —Sean